# SparseArray remove() and delete() what's the difference?

Tags: android, sparse-array

What is the main difference between calling remove() or delete() on a SparseArray, because they both accept key's as arguments.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. Quoting [the documentation for `remove()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#remove%28int%29):

> Alias for delete(int).

In other words, they do the same thing. In [the current implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java), `remove()` calls `delete()`.